# Java jersey rest Service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, jersey

I am using Java jersey Restful service running on Tomcat server...
In my service i  have a method like this

```
@Produces("text/plain")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
    @HeaderParam("Filename") String Filename) {
    String uploadedFileLocation = "D://FileUpload/" + Filename;
    ImageUpload filewrite = new ImageUpload();
}
```

But I am getting the error

```
Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response Restservice_Java.Hello.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,java.lang.String) at parameter at index 0
```

Can anyone help me in this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you should always respond with Response :

```
@Produces("text/plain")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
    @HeaderParam("Filename") String Filename) {
    String uploadedFileLocation = "D://FileUpload/" + Filename;
    ImageUpload filewrite = new ImageUpload();


   // if(error==true) return Response.status(400).build();
    return Response.ok().entity("job done").build();
}
```

The object Response can return a [http w3C status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) and a message with `.entity("example")`.
See the [Response - jersey doc](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html)

Enjoy jersey ! give me some feedbacks please . :)

Comment: Jean u have any idea abt this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054200/sending-large-image-in-chunks