# Sending Large Image in chunks

Tags: java, android, web-services, tomcat, chunking

I am sending images from my android client to java jersey restful service and I succeded in doing that.But my issue is when I try to send large images say > 1MB its consumes more time so I like to send image in **CHUNKS** can anyone help me in doing this.How to send(**POST**) image stream in CHUNKS to server

Comment: responded on a speed because is a very ample question. give me feedback! enjoy

Answer (score 0):

references used :

- [server code & client call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326460/upload-a-large-file-using-jersey-client)
- [server function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326460/upload-a-large-file-using-jersey-client)

  ```
  /*** SERVER SIDE CODE****/

   @POST
   @Path("/upload/{attachmentName}")
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
      public void uploadAttachment(
              @PathParam("attachmentName") String attachmentName, 
              @FormParam("input") InputStream attachmentInputStream) {               
      InputStream content = request.getInputStream();

  // do something better than this
  OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("content.txt");
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int len;
  while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      // whatever processing you want here
      out.write(buffer, 0, len);
  }
   out.close();

   return Response.status(201).build();
  }


        /**********************************************/


   /** 
     CLIENT SIDE CODE
   **/
      // .....
    client.setChunkedEncodingSize(1024);
    WebResource rootResource = client.resource("your-server-base-url");
      File file = new File("your-file-path");
     InputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(file);
      String contentDisposition = "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"";
      ClientResponse response = rootResource.path("attachment").path("upload").path("your-file-name")
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).header("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition)
           .post(ClientResponse.class, fileInStream);
  ```

You should split the file in the client and restore part of the file in the server. 
and after that you should merge the files together. Take a look at [split /merge file on coderanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/436301/java/java/split-file)

Enjoy ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another path is available, if you don't want to code too much consider using : 
[file upload apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html) that is great ! :)